# Too Many objects in single instance of ObjectMapper SerializerCache causing memory leak

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

We are running a spring boot based service with which, we are having GC issues on running perf tests. When we looked at the heap dump on Eclipse plugin "Memory Analysis Toolkit" (MAT), we found below:

```
One instance of "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x1000050b8" occupies 2,057,443,904 (93.15%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.SerializerCache" loaded by "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x1000050b8".
Keywords
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.SerializerCache
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x1000050b8
```

Not really sure what's going on here. Why is SerializerCache holding onto so many objects in Map, and, how to clear it out.

Using
SpringIO: 2.0.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

The SpringIO 2.0.6.RELEASE uses jackson version 2.6.7, which, incidentally, doesn't show up on the Jackson release page of master branch (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/release-notes/VERSION).
I upgraded my application to use jackson version 2.8.1 and it fixed the issues.